# PHP alert message in persian language

Tags: javascript, php, alert, persian, farsi

I have a delete page, I am trying to get an alert message to popup If the delete operation was performed, Display.
I want to show text message in alert box in Persian (Farsi) language, but This code is done but Persian characters do not display correctly.
 please help me What should I do?

```
 echo '<script>';
 echo 'alert("حذف");';
 echo 'location.href="Delete Touristplace1.php"';
 echo '</script>';
```

Comment: use utf-8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: what the alert gives you ??

Comment: Works ok for me :http://jsfiddle.net/5xTph/  what is the character set of your page set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer:

Set UTF-8 as the character set for all headers output by your PHP code

```
In every PHP output header, specify UTF-8 as the encoding:

  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a meta tag for the HTML on which you want this alert,
you have set the character set which is suitable for persian language.
usually following works 
`charset="UTF-8"`
if this doesn't work, use
`charset="ISO-8859-1"`